# Jquery datepicker in django doesn't show the drop down table

Tags: python, django, datepicker

There is no error alert, but there is no dropdown table to choose the date. I want to use the datepicker of jquery to realize this function.

**html code**

```
<html> 
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>  
    <title>Input Table</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#id_startdate" ).datepicker();
      });
    </script>        
</head>  

<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>  
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
class input(models.Model):
    start_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import input
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
import Queue
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateTimeWidget, DateWidget, TimeWidget
from django.forms import widgets
from django.forms import extras
from functools import partial

DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})
class inputform(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
class Meta:
    model = input
    fields = ('start_date')
    widgets = {
        'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-cross-browser-datepickers-in-minutes--net-20236

I followed the example on this post and then it works. Mainly I changed the html code as follows:

```
<html> 
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>  
    <title>Input Table</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
</head>  

<body> 
    <p>Start Date:<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" /></p>
    <script>
       (function() {
          var elem = document.createElement('input');
          elem.setAttribute('type', 'date');

          if ( elem.type === 'text' ) {
             $('#date').datepicker(); 
          }
       })();

    </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling .datepicker() on a non-existent field, no field has `#id_startdate` as their id.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#id_startdate" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

should be :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

i would also suggest you pass the form logic to your forms.py

Comment: Hi, thank you, but the it still shows no error on the page, but no drop down date table on the html page....